# IEnumerable<Object> Data Specific Ordering

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I've an object that is include property **ID** with values between 101 and 199. How to order it like `199,101,102 ... 198`?

In result I want to put last item to first.

Comment: the logic of ordering is not very clear. Can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: `object` does not have an `ID` property, what is your type, with an `ID` property?

Comment: @Jodrell - the OP is talking about an arbitrary type with a property ID, not System.Object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The desired ordering makes no sense (some reasoning would be helpful), but this should do the trick:

```
int maxID = items.Max(x => x.ID); // If you want the Last item instead of the one
                                  // with the greatest ID, you can use
                                  // items.Last().ID instead.
var strangelyOrderedItems = items
    .OrderBy(x => x.ID == maxID ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenBy(x => x.ID);
```

Comment: instead of 199, probably the OP wants Max() or Last()

Comment: @AdrianIftode: Thought about that too, but as long as the requirement says `199`, I'll use `199`, too ;)

Comment: "Last item to first" is not actually 199 ( I didn't downvote you, actually I gave a +1, being the simplest and most readable solution)

Comment: If you do e.g. `.OrderBy(x => x.ID == maxID ? long.MaxValue : (long)x.ID)` you can get away with a single sort? Then this must be about as efficient as possible, one sort and one extra iteration to get the max. (Short of writing your own sort that keeps the biggest at the start as it goes...)

Comment: @Jodrell This never compares 0 or 1 to real item IDs, does it?

Comment: @Rawling, you should make your comment an answer but, won't `long.MaxValue` go to the end, perhaps `long.MinValue` or `(long)(-1)` is better

Comment: ... yeah, `MinValue`, of course. Doh. I'm not going to post it as my own answer as my own (posted and deleted) response was rubbish compared to this and I don't want to steal it :D

Answer (score 1):

Depending whether you are interested in the largest item in the list, or the last item in the list:

```
internal sealed class Object : IComparable<Object>
{
   private readonly int mID; 
   public int ID { get { return mID; } }
   public Object(int pID) { mID = pID; }

   public static implicit operator int(Object pObject) { return pObject.mID; }
   public static implicit operator Object(int pInt) { return new Object(pInt); }

   public int CompareTo(Object pOther) { return mID - pOther.mID; }
   public override string ToString() { return string.Format("{0}", mID); }
}


List<Object> myList = new List<Object> { 1, 2, 6, 5, 4, 3 };

// the last item first
List<Object> last = new List<Object> { myList.Last() };
List<Object> lastFirst = 
   last.Concat(myList.Except(last).OrderBy(x => x)).ToList();

lastFirst.ForEach(Console.Write);
Console.WriteLine();
// outputs: 312456     

// or

// the largest item first
List<Object> max = new List<Object> { myList.Max() };
List<Object> maxFirst = 
   max.Concat(myList.Except(max).OrderBy(x => x)).ToList();

maxFirst.ForEach(Console.Write);
Console.WriteLine();
// outputs: 612345
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: missed the part about you wanting the last item first. You could do it like this :

```
var objectList = new List<DataObject>();
var lastob = objectList.Last();
objectList.Remove(lastob);
var newList = new List<DataObject>();
newList.Add(lastob);
newList.AddRange(objectList.OrderBy(o => o.Id).ToList());
```

If you are talking about a normal sorting you could use linq's order by method like this :
 
`objectList = objectList.OrderBy(ob => ob.ID).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

> In result I want to put last item to first

first sort the list

```
List<int> values = new List<int>{100, 56, 89..}; 
var result = values.OrderBy(x=>x);
```

add an extension method for swaping an elements in the `List<T>`

```
static void Swap<T>(this List<T> list, int index1, int index2)
{
     T temp = list[index1];
     list[index1] = list[index2];
     list[index2] = temp;
}
```

after use it

```
result .Swap(0, result.Count -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this using a single Linq statment.

```
var ordering = testData
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.Id)
    .Take(1)
    .Union(testData.OrderBy(t => t.Id).Take(testData.Count() - 1));
```

Order it in reverse direction and take the top 1, then order it the "right way round" and take all but the last and union these together. There are quite a few variants of this approach, but the above should work.

This approach should work for arbitrary lists too, without the need to know the max number.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var orderedItems = items.OrderBy(x => x.Id)
var orderedItemsLastFirst = 
    orderedItems.Reverse().Take(1).Concat(orderedItems.Skip(1));
```

This will iterate the list several times so perhaps could be more efficient but doesn't use much code.

If more speed is important you could write a specialised IEnumerable extension that would allow you to sort and return without converting to an intermediate IEnumerable.

Answer (score -3):

```
var myList = new List<MyObject>();
//initialize the list
var ordered = myList.OrderBy(c => c.Id); //or use OrderByDescending if you want reverse order
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the OPs problem of wanting the last item in the ordering to be placed at the top of the list.